# I am trying to run caddy server with docker on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, but caddy not starting

Tags: docker, ubuntu, caddy

I am trying to run caddy 1 server with docker on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, but caddy not starting. when i do

'docker-compose up' then it gives error as

````
Creating app ... done
Attaching to app
app | panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range
app |
app | goroutine 1 [running]:
app | github.com/miekg/dns.ClientConfigFromFile(0xd2ed4a, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
app |      /gopath/src/github.com/miekg/dns/clientconfig.go:86 +0x948
app | github.com/xenolf/lego/acme.getNameservers(0xd2ed4a, 0x10, 0x1328d20, 0x2, 0x2, 0x0, 0xc42003bf58, 0x4f28d1)
app |      /gopath/src/github.com/xenolf/lego/acme/dns_challenge.go:40 +0x4d
app | github.com/xenolf/lego/acme.init()
app |      /gopath/src/github.com/xenolf/lego/acme/dns_challenge.go:33 +0x12d
app | github.com/mholt/caddy/caddy/caddymain.init()
app |      /tmp/gopath_05-25-0332.428952110/src/github.com/mholt/caddy/caddy/caddymain/run.go:243 +0x75
app | main.init()
app |      /tmp/gopath_05-25-0332.428952110/src/github.com/mholt/caddy/caddy/main.go:15 +0x44 ```


and server not started
````

Comment: Could you provide a lot more detail?  Your caddyfile, how you are staring Caddy, Caddy version etc?

Comment: When searching for a solution about a similar issue, I ran into this issue report which contains some workaround: https://github.com/stefanprodan/dockprom/issues/205#issuecomment-798628548